# Rollover table shows hidden span class text with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, hover

I have a `<tr>` class that upon rollover of the entire row with the mouse, I'd like some text that is contained within one of the cells to appear. If possible, can this be done with CSS, and how is it possible to have a rollover of the whole table row show the text previously hidden in one of the cells, the same should also apply for any other rows that have a cell in them with their own hidden text within a cell. I understand it might need jQuery to accomplish this, but if possible in just pure CSS this would be preferred.

Here's an example, the rollovers on the forum names showing the child forums: http://www.kanyetothe.com/forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can easily be achieved with css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<style>
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }

    tr:hover .hidden {
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
        <td class="hidden">Row 1 Column 2</td>
        <td>Row 1 Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
        <td class="hidden">Row 2 Column 2</td>
        <td>Row 2 Column 3</td>
    </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```